# how to deploy an app on heroku running with rails/nginx/node/redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nginx, redis

I have an app running locally on Ruby on Rails, and nginx is my assets server. I have node server running for the real time stuff. The js file that runs with node is in the rails application folder. Redis subcription is used for the intermediate store between node and rails. So, it lies in the js file. It is subscribing the data from sql server trigger action. Redis Server is running as a service.

With this brief scenario, do any of you have rough idea, how I can go about deploying an app with all these in heroku?

Any opinion is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Sagar